# how can i get an object's value from an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this array with several id's and heights.

How can i get a hight of a specific id given?

like get the value of review-1 from the array? which is "500px"?

thanks.

```
 ar=[];
 ar.push({"id":"reiew-1","height":"500px"});

 $.each(ar,function(index,value){

 alert(value.height); // gets all the heights

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go `functional` and do something like this:

```
ar=[
    {"id":"reiew-1","height":"500px"},
    {"id":"reiew-2","height":"600px"},
    {"id":"reiew-3","height":"700px"},
];

filterById=function(value){
    return function(o){
        return o["id"]===value;
    };        
}

getAttribute=function(value){
    return function(o){
        return o[value];
    }
}

ar.filter(filterById("reiew-1")).map(getAttribute("height"))
```

Which is easy on the eyes :]

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LEm62/)

For more information (e.g. about browser compatibility), here are the MDN links:[`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 1):

Use an if condition within the loop

```
ar = [];
ar.push({
    "id": "reiew-1",
    "height": "500px"
});

$.each(ar, function (index, value) {
    if (value.id == 'reiew-1') {
        alert(value.height); // gets all the heights
        return false;//stop further looping of the array since the value you are looking for is found
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

So you can use only javascript methods to do this things

```
var ar=[];
ar.push({"id":"reiew-1","height":"500px"}, {"id":"reiew-3","height":"500px"});

// function that filter and return object with selected id
function getById(array, id){
  return array.filter(function(item){
    return item.id == id;
  })[0].height || null;
}

// now you can use this method
console.log(getById(ar, "reiew-1"))
```

You can play with this code, [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8fpS/1)

Comment: That's in the right dircetion. But he wants the "height" of a specific `id` ;) Perhaps you add that to your code.

Comment: sorry)) I lost this thing))